# CSS: li > a margin

Tags: css, margin, html-lists

```
#top-menu ul.menu li {
  background: url(img/back-top-menu2.png);
  width: 70px;
  height: 37px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#top-menu ul.menu li:hover {
  background: url(img/back-top-menu.png);
}

#top-menu ul.menu li a { 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none; 
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[image]

How to make margin-top works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a>` is an inline element. Add "`display:block;`" or "`display:inline-block;`" to it to make it a block level element. Properties like "margin" and "padding" only work on block level elements.

Answer (score 2):

try padding-top instead.

The other way is to add display:block and then give it also a height of 37px, and then add a `line-height:37px`